# Magento dynamic product attribute

Tags: magento, attributes, customization

I'd like to have a set of products that are available within a certain zip code range. All the products are supposed to be "grouped" underneath a single product. When you want to add a product to the cart, you type in your zip code, and get a list of products you can select which match the zip code entered.

How would one achieve something like this? I've looked into configurable products, but I don't believe that will give me the needed functionality out of the box.

Comment: Why are they limited to this postcode range ? Because they are kind of activities and you need to go to that particular place to use the item purchased or because you don't want to sell out of the postcode range ?

Comment: You need to : 
1°)use the postcode range as a product attribute  
2°)change the filtering function to allow filtering one postcode in ranges
3°)add a default filtering on all page once user typed his postcode
4°)eventually double check at checkout to prevent cheaters if this is a problem for you

This will not be possible out of the box